# Infimum of fractal dimensions left by almost-disjoint-disk covering of plane

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36036/covering-the-plane-with-disks) show that it is not possible to cover the plane by almost-disjoint closed disks. As note in the comments, the [Appollonian Gasket](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApollonianGasket.html) leaves a set of fractal dimension approximately $1.3$ uncovered.

**What is the infimum of the fractal dimensions of sets left uncovered? Is it achieved?**